# How do I GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on ALL VIEWS in one statement?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

In PostgreSQL 9+, is there a way to
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on ALL VIEWS in schema schema_name TO role_name`
in a single statement?

Answer (score 11):

The only way to do this in a single statement (kind of) is to create a function, otherwise you are either specifically listing all views or you are granting to all tables, then revoking non-views.

I wrote this quickly, but tested it. You may need to tweak as needed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_grant_all_views(schema_name TEXT, role_name TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS $func$

DECLARE view_name TEXT;

BEGIN

  FOR view_name IN
    SELECT viewname FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname = schema_name
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ' || schema_name || '.' || view_name || ' TO ' || role_name || ';';
  END LOOP;

END; $func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Usage:

```
SELECT fn_grant_all_views('my_schema','my_role');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this from the command line:

1. Login as postgres:

   `sudo -i -u postgres`
2. Run this command:

   `psql -At -d [dbname] -c "SELECT 'GRANT ALL ON '||viewname||' TO [username];' FROM pg_views WHERE schemaname='public';" | psql -d [dbname]`